# how to test controller methods in c#

Tags: c#, api, controller, nunit, moq

I have recently started unit testing c# code But I never tested controller classes before. I have following class I need to write test cases for this.

```
namespace nH.MasterData.API.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/AType")]
    public class ATypeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProcessor _domain;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private const string Version = "VERSION_1";
        private const string Model = "model";
        private const string Entity = "AType";

        public ATypeController(IProxy proxy, ILogger<ATypeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            var proxy = proxy.GetProxy();
            _domain = new InstitutionAddressProcessor(proxy);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public OkObjectResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(_domain.GetATypesMembers(Model, Version, Entity, MemberType.Leaf, null));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
                return new OkObjectResult(BadRequest());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here, `_domain.GetATypesMembers()` is not in my project and I am not creating the object of `_domain` explicitly (Its created inside the constructor). How Do I get control over the object which is being created in constructor? So that I can mock the response when called without actually making actual call.

Usually, I would `setup` the mock on the object as `wcfMockService.Setup(x => x.GetATypesMembers(...).ReturnAsync(response);` But how can I write for this one?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Edit1: 
creating objects inside the constructor is bad practice. But this is a legacy code and being used in many places. So I am just trying to write tests as the code exists.

Answer (score 3):

What you are experiencing first hand is why it is bad design to tightly couple your classes to implementation concerns.

That controller should be refactored to depend on abstractions and not on concretions.

```
namespace nH.MasterData.API.Controllers {
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/AType")]
    public class ATypeController : Controller {
        private readonly IProcessor _domain;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private const string Version = "VERSION_1";
        private const string Model = "model";
        private const string Entity = "AType";

        public ATypeController(IProcessor domain, ILogger<ATypeController> logger) {
            _logger = logger;            
            _domain = domain;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get() {
            try {
                return Ok(_domain.GetATypesMembers(Model, Version, Entity, MemberType.Leaf, null));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the dependencies can be mocked as needed when testing

```
var processor = new Mock<IProcessor>();
var logger = new Mock<ILogger<ATypeController>>();
var controller = new ATypeController(processor.Object, logger.Object); 

//...setup mocks
```

From the looks of the original constructor it looks like `IProcessor` should be configured accordingly to satisfy its dependencies as its constructor is not truthful about its dependency which required an intermediary call before injection.

This can be satisfied at the composition root.

```
services.AddScoped<IProcessor>(_ => {                
    var proxy = _.GetService<IProxy>();
    return new InstitutionAddressProcessor(proxy.GetProxy());
});
```

Comment: yeah i know thats the best practice, But I can not modify that logic since its a legacy code and being used in many places. Could you please suggest me a way to test this way?

Comment: @Extreme there is no way for Moq to get around the `new InstitutionAddressProcessor` in the controller's constructor.

Comment: @Extreme while probably more difficult would you be able mock the proxy enough to let the `InstitutionAddressProcessor` implementation to be invoked without any adverse effects?

Comment: @ Nkosi, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Extreme show relevant code for `InstitutionAddressProcessor` and lets see if there is one or not.

Comment: I am refactoring the constructor as you're suggesting. How would the dependency be injected in the application? Does `InstitutionAddressProcessor` be injected with the `IProxy` into `ATypeController`? how do I tell CLR to inject `InstitutionAddressProcessor` with `IProxy`?

Comment: @Extreme  Yes `InstitutionAddressProcessor` will be injected with the `IProxy` into `ATypeController`. Set services configuration code shown above lets the DI container know that when ever `IProcessor` is injected as a dependency, to use the delegate factor shown to inject the that implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, you are not able to correct the constructor to use a proper DI model, and you can't get around that. Assuming you have a valid `IProxy` instance you can inject to satisfy the object construction properly, you can turn to some dirty reflection hacks to get your `IProcessor` mock in.

Something along the lines of this should let you set the field after you constructed your sut.

```
// Arrange
var sut = SutProvider.GetATypeController(); // A system under test factory.

var mock = new Mock<IProcessor>();
// ... mock setup ..

typeof(ATypeController)
    .GetField("_domain", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .SetValue(sut, mock.Object);

// Act
var result = sut.Get();

// Assert
// ... assertions of result
```

This isn't an *ideal* setup, but when working with legacy code you will sometimes have to do dirty things to set the proper state of an object for testing. I strongly recommend you keep those things inside of tests only, with appropriate commentary about never doing this in 'real' code.

SutProvider is a simple factory, the implementation can look like this:

```
public class SutProvider 
{
    public static ATypeController GetATypeController() => new ATypeController(GetProxy(), GetATypeControllerLogger());

    public static IProxy GetProxy() {
        // Either return a valid IProxy, or set up a mock that can return a result from the GetProxy method that is valid enough to withstand InstitutionAddressProcessor's constructor.
    }

    public static ILogger<ATypeController> GetATypeControllerLogger() => new Mock<ILogger<ATypeController>>().Object;
}
```

You are likely going to need to dive a bit into the `InstitutionAddressProcessor`'s constructor to figure out the best way to pass it a valid-enough proxy.

Comment: I would say this still requires to remove the readonly flag, but that should be a minor issue

Comment: @Simons0n readonly is used at compile time, it does not stop reflection from forcibly changing the value, so it should be fine to proceed without modifying the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is this case. Its a form of [Inversion Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). Instead of passing proxy and  _domain in the method, I'll pass it as an argument (proxy is being passed, but I'll pass the _domain as an argument). The _domain will be instantiated somewhere in `Main like method` or one can use `['AutoFac']`. Then it becomes easy to create unit tests.

Here is a useful link on testing Controllers using [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api)

As above user have pointed, there is a tight coupling which makes it hard to unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get anything for free.  If you want to be able to test logic you have to decouple things.  If you don't decouple them you are going to be unable to properly test, because you are testing something with a dependency you yourself cannot test for.  So there is no 
"Unit".

Having said that it may be legacy code but a decent tool like resharper, with whom I am not at all affiliated with, can help you with your refactoring.  Once you inject the service then you can do a proper unit test.